# PHP Regex check if contains one or more specified characters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to check if my string contains one of the following characters: !@#$&*  However, whenever I run the test, it always returns false.  I am not very versed in Regex and I've been looking at numerous examples and they all seem to point that this is correct, however I guess it is not since it is failing.  Can somebody tell me what would be the correct check?

```
if(!preg_match("#[!@#$&*]+#", $value)){
    return "Character not found";
}
else{
    return "Character found!";
}
```

Test string is JohnDoe1@

Comment: You need to escape the delimiter.

Comment: it returns false because `JohnDoe1` is a word so if you need it to work with alphanumeric characters modify it to `/\w+[!@#$&*]+/`

Comment: You also don't need the quantifier. `[!@#$&*]` would be any one of those characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `"#[!@#$&*]+#"` with `"#[!@\#\$&*]+#"`

Your # delimiter is conflicting and as a secondary your $ might be parsed as a variable because you've got double quotes.

Other option includes single quotes and a different delimter `'/[!@#$&*]+/'`

Answer (score 1):

Its failing because you are using the delimiter inside the regex without
escaping it.

Try a different delimiter

```
"~[!@#$&*]+~"
```

or escape the delimiter

```
"#[!@\#$&*]+#"
```